# iPhone Dev - How to make a UITableView the exact height to fit all of the cells in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0nDcS.png]

I would like to make it so that the tableview stops right at the "So" cell, instead of having all the blank cells under it (the big plan is to have a bunch of multiple choice questions like the one in that pic, all on top of one another on one scrollview). I'm guessing I need to set the tableView's frame, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to calculate at runtime the exact height of the portion of the tableview where the cells are implemented (the ones with text in the pic). It's tricky because I made it so that each cell's height can change to accommodate the amount of text in it. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: You can add images to a post, and it's often better than simply linking to the image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two appproaches you can take.

Best and easiest.
1. Add a footer view to the table so it will not draw the rows after the last row. a blank footer view will do.

```
       //Add empty view to hide trailing row seperators
UIView *emptyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0)];
emptyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[tableView setTableFooterView:emptyView];
[emptyView release];
```

2.Check how many rows you have in the tableview and calculate the tableheight and change the frame of table view.

Comment: Thanks! The empty footer was a great idea. Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack (so wait to see if a better solution comes along):

Use `numberOfSections` to get the number of sections (if you later change to grouped style), and then add up the `height`s of `rectForSection:` for each of the sections (in plain style, just take `rectForSection:0`). Maybe add a bit to this for the separators.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a `tableView:sizeOfAllCells:` function if that is what you are looking for. From your question it sounds like you to adjust the size of your table so you can put other content on bottom of it.

You are correct is saying that you want to alter your UITableView's frame property to match the height.

```
[table setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,table.frame.size.width,heightOfCells)];
```

There are a few things you could do though. If you had an array of all the cells, you could loop through it real quick and add the height of each of them. You could (I don't particularly recommend it though) loop though the number of sections and rows you have, using `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:` instead of having an array of cells, and get the heights that way. If each cell is the same height (sounds like its possible it wont be) you could just do some simple math to figure out the height. Lastly, you could keep a dictionary or array of heights and update it in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndex:` so if the content changes, it updates the size, but then you would have to call a `reloadData`. Those are just a few ideas of ways to solve this particular problem.